# Translation bundling error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

I've recently updated my Ruby on Rails project and then when I try to run the 
`rake i18n:js:export` command, I'm getting the following error

`uninitialized constant I18n::INTERPOLATION_PATTERN`

This happens in both windows 8.1 and centos6 machines.

My ruby version is: 1.8.7 in windows and 1.9.3 in CentOS6
Rails version: 3.0.9

I'm clueless in this spot and tried to find a solution, and couldn't find a correct one.

I'm using `i18n-js version 2.1.2`

I tried updating it to `version 3.0.0.rc5` but still no luck.

Anyone came across any issues similar to this? I'm eagerly expecting a solution to fix this issue.

[image]

/* RESULT AFTER RUNNING WITH TRACE */

> ** Invoke i18n:js:export (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Execute i18n:js:export rake aborted! uninitialized constant I18n::INTERPOLATION_PATTERN
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js.rb:72:in
>   `block in  configured_segments'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js.rb:70:in`
>   each'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js.rb:70:in
>   `each_wit h_object'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js.rb:70:in`
>   configur ed_segments'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js.rb:83:in
>   `translat ion_segments'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js.rb:46:in`
>   export!'
>
> c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2/lib/i18n-js/rake.rb:9:in
>   `bloc k (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in`
>   call'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in
>   `block i n execute'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in`
>   each'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in
>   `execute '
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in`
>   block i n invoke_with_call_chain'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in`
>   invoke_ with_call_chain'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in
>   `invoke'
>
> c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in
>   `invoke_task'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>    block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `each'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`
>    block in top_level'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in
>   `run_with_threads'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in`
>    top_level'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in
>   `b lock in run'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in`
>    standard_exception_handling'
>   c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in
>   `r un' c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in`
>    ' c:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
>   c:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in`' Tasks: TOP => i18n:js:export

Thanks

Comment: Is there more stack trace? Does it reference a line in your file, and if so what is the code on that line?

Comment: @Beartech: I've updated the question and now added the stack trace from the centos. Could you please check it

Comment: When you say you updated, what did you change? Do you mean you updated the Rails version? You could try running the `rake` command with --trace to get more info. It's complaining that it can't find the constant I18n::INTERPOLATION_PATTERN defined anywhere. Is there a `require...` missing somewhere?

Comment: Can you post your `config/i18n-js.yml` file?

Comment: @Beartech: I added the result after I run with trace.

And this is my i18n-js file

`auto_export: no

translations:
  - file: "public/javascripts/translations.js"
    only: "*"

asset_pipeline: yes
`

Comment: OK, the problem is getting the constant `INTERPOLATION_PATTERN` from the i18n gem that i18n-js depends on. Make sure you are in the root directory of your app (same place you would run the `rake...` command) and run `bundle show i18n` and show us the output.

Comment: Also IMPORTANT, is your Rails app running under Rails 3? Rails 2? Need to know!

Comment: Hi

My rails version is: 3.0.9 and this is the gem path

`$ bundle show i18n-js
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-js-2.1.2`

Comment: No, you need to do `bundle show` for `i18n`, not `i18n-js`.

Comment: Following is the result for `i18n`

`$ bundle show i18n
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.3`

Comment: And finally, in the rails console (run `rails c`) just type `I18n::INTERPOLATION_PATTERN` and hit enter. Must be copied exactly as shown.

Comment: `irb(main):001:0> I18n::INTERPOLATION_PATTERN
NameError: uninitialized constant I18n::INTERPOLATION_PATTERN
        from (irb):1
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/comman
ds/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44850/discussion-between-mujahid-and-beartech)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an outdated issue, but you may want to look at this recent SO question.  It details how I ran into a similar issue and how it was resolved:

[upgrading to ruby 2.3.0 NameError: uninitialized constant I18n::Config::Backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707775/upgrading-to-ruby-2-3-0-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-i18nconfigbackend)

Look through your rake files and see if you have any references to the Translation helper.

Removing include `ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper` and replacing `(t "some_text")` with `(I18n.t "some_text")` completely resolved the issue.