# upgrading to ruby 2.3.0 NameError: uninitialized constant I18n::Config::Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I just upgraded Ruby 2.2.2 to 2.3.0. Whenever I run a rake task I get the following error:

```
Christians-Air:my_rails_app cman77$ rake --trace
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant I18n::Config::Backend
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:19:in `backend'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:147:in `translate'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb:69:in `translate'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:19:in `backend'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:147:in `translate'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/actionview-4.2.6/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb:69:in `translate'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `each'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:452:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in `load_tasks'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/cman77/Dropbox/rails_projects/my_rails_app/Rakefile:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/cman77/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jbio.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Anyone have experience with this?  I am really stuck in terms of how to even begin to diagnose/remedy this issue.

Here is the contents of my Rakefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

ENV['NEWRELIC_ENABLE'] = 'false'

MyRailsApp::Application.load_tasks
```

This appears to be the offending line referenced in the I18n gem:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/config.rb#L18

**Update**: it seems to be tied to the use of `include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper` in one of my rake files.  If I remove that line I can run rake commands.

**Update2**: Removing `include ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper` and replacing `(t "some_text")` with `(I18n.t "some_text")` completely resolved the issue.  I will still award the bounty to anyone who can explain why this broke with a Ruby upgrade!

Comment: Can you provide something that helps us reproduce your error?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/Users/cman77/Dropbox/rails_projects/my_rails_app/Rakefile`

Comment: @Sebin I added the contents of the Rakefile.

Comment: Are you sure it was just the ruby upgrade or you might have actually upgraded the `i18n` gem as well? If so, what was the original version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you experienced that problem because you ere using the `t` method (an helper for controllers and views) in a rake task, instead of the standard `I18n.t`.

This is an uncommon and unconventional approach, so you have fallen in a possible regression that [few have experienced](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/337) and it has a simple solution, like the one you found: stick to the conventions.